# When click drop down menu opens all sub menus

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with several sub menus and when I click to open one of the sub menus, all sub menus all openned. How can I open only the clicked sub menu?

*I know that this has been asked several times but I can NOT figure out how to fix my problem.*

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-top-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Jquery:

```
  $('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.sub-menu').slideDown(100);
        $('.menu-item-has-children').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
      else{
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp(100);
        $('.menu-item-has-children').toggleClass('active');
      }
  });
```

The code can be find here on codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXQNLo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this `$(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(100);` instead of `$('.sub-menu').slideDown(100);`

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(100);
        $('.menu-item-has-children').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
      else{
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp(100);
        $('.menu-item-has-children').toggleClass('active');
      }
  });
```

[Check this your updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOQMZo)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you here my code:

when the **menu-item-has-children** clicked then the check and a get action else another action.

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideUp(300);
  }
  else{
      $('#menu-main-top-menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu').slideUp(300);
      $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown(300);
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
a.active { 
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-top-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Top Item with Sub Items</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Top Item </a></li>
</ul>
```